# Health for Kafka Binder is always UNKNOWN

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

When I try to activate the health indicator for the kafka binder as explained in [Spring Cloud Stream Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_health_indicator)

the health endpoint returns:

```
binders":{"status":"UNKNOWN","kafka":{"status":"UNKNOWN"}}}
```

my configuration contains as documented:

```
 management.health.binders.enabled=true
```

I already debugged `BindersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` and noticed, that no `HealthIndicator`is registered in the `binderContext`. Do I have to register a custom `HealthIndicator` as bean or what steps are necessary?

Comment: Which version of Kafka binder do you use? I could see the Kafka binder health indicator in the binderContext when using 1.2.x.

Comment: @IlayaperumalGopinathan I'm using 1.2.0. So in theory the property mentioned above should do everything needed?

Comment: Same thing happens to me using `spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder`, which isn't Kafka

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the documentation. By default, the binders health indicators are enabled. If you want to disable, then you would need to specify `management.health.binders.enabled=false`.

Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: Also, setting `management.health.binders.enabled=true` explicitly doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/950. Let me know if you have the binders health indicator enabled by default (without setting that property to true explicitly)

Comment: You are right - If I remove the property, the health endpoint still contains the binders health part.

Comment: I have the same issue for release 2.1.3. Was this ever fixed?

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

management.health.binders.enabled = true
management.health.kafka.enabled = true

management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS

```
localhost:8080/actuator/health

{
"status": "UP",
"details": {
    "kafka": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "details": {
            "total": 274622050304,
            "free": 269098790912,
            "threshold": 10485760
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
@Component
```

public class KafkaHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaHealthIndicator.class);

```
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafka;

public KafkaHealthIndicator(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafka) {
    this.kafka = kafka;
}

/**
 * Return an indication of health.
 *
 * @return the health for Kafka.
 */
@Override
public Health health() {
    try {
        kafka.send("kafka-health-indicator", "❥").get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        return Health.down(e).build();
    }
    return Health.up().build();
}
```

}