# Spring-Cloud-Stream-Kafka Custom Health check is not giving Kafka status

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I have tried to add custom Kafka health check followed the same example set in the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162841/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-custom-health-check-not-working -----` 
But I am not getting the desired result.
When I hit link `localhost:8080/actuator/health`, It gives

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "details": {
        "healthIndicator": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 274622050304,
                "free": 269102321664,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should come like

`"binders": { "status": "UP", "kafka": { "status": "UP", "healthIndicator": { "status": "UP" } } }`,

Can Anybody give suggestion on this ?

Comment: I am able to solve this.

Comment: am able to solve this.
Please see link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842733/health-for-kafka-binder-is-always-unknown/56287840#56287840
posted by Taufique Alam